# What about adding a tab with my Beta and Committed SE sites on the SE drop Menu?

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, user-interface, global-inbox

It would be a nice feature to have a special tab menu next to the inbox menu for instance, (in the StackExchange drop-down menu), with the links of the Beta and Committed SE sites in which I'm involved.

Currently, it's a bit tricky to have easy & direct access to them...
It will remind me to check and participate.

Comment: Yes agreed! It would be convenient

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would be especially nice for the Beta sites that aren't listed at the bottom of the home page, since you have to memorize them, or as I have done, keep the original beta email so I can find them when I need to.
I agree it would also give a reminder to us to keep our participation up.

It would be simple to add another link that says something like 'Beta Sites' like so:

[image: Beta Sites in Global Inbox]

Answer (score 2):

Providing a link to the beta sites where you can view your subscribed sites and other betas would allow users to browse more easily. I think that this would increase participation on beta sites both of subscribed members and those who have not seen the beta sites yet.

Answer (score 1):

What about going to your profile and clicking the accounts tab is tricky?

[image]

Yours are at:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/142402/pierre?tab=accounts

They're also listed on your network profile at:

https://stackexchange.com/users/58013?tab=accounts

I don't think this is necessary.  The top bar has a lot of information, but it's currently mostly unobtrusive.  If you want something easily accessible from a dropdown, use a bookmark folder in your toolbar.